# Select and update from same field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `library` with fields `value` and `key`.I have a column named **e_book** inside `value`(fieldname).

select its keyvalue and i need to increment 1 to the keyvalue and update it and return it.Can anyone help me to write an sql function for the above condition.I am new to sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a function ? Or an SQL . Below is the SQL .

```
UPDATE library
SET key = key + 1
WHERE value = 'e_book';
```